# Wordpress .htaccess rewrite for custom template

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am trying to convert a website to WordPress. The URLs in use are currently in the format:                   `http://www.example.com/database/44/category/short-item-description.html`

To display items that are stored in the database, I have created a page template DatabaseFetch.php and have added a page to WordPress to use this template at address     `http://www.example.com/database/` (this can also be access by `http://www.example.com/index.php?p=39`)

The template DatabaseFetch.php will have the PHP code to get the ID number from the URL and then use this ID number to get the relevant item details from the database.

I am trying to alter the .htaccess file found in the WordPress root folder as I want all URLs in the format of `http://www.example.com/database/44/category/short-item-description.html` to be processed by `http://www.example.com/database/` but I want the browser to display the URL in the format of `http://www.example.com/database/44/category/short-item-description.html` (ie the URL not to change)

I have tried many combinations over the last couple days but I cannot get it working. Using the line:

```
RewriteRule ^/?database/([0-9]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*).html$ /database/ [NC,L]
```

brings up WordPress 404 page.

Using the line:

```
RewriteRule ^/?database/([0-9]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*).html$ /?p=39 [NC,L]
```

brings up correct page, but the URL in the browser changes to `http://www.example.com/database/`
Does anyone know how I need to alter the .htaccess file below to get the desired results I seek?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# RewriteRule ^/?database/([0-9]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*).html$  /database/ [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/?database/([0-9]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*).html$  /?p=39 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I have also tried both lines with flags and no flags and combination of flags but nothing gets the desired result. On a non-Wordpress installation, I have the desired outcome defined by one line in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^/?database/([0-9]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*).html$ database.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

The problem with WordPress is that the database page I need is not the physical DatabaseFetch.php file. therefore how do I go about the rewrite? Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use an .htaccess rule, use WordPress internal rewrite system.

First, add a query var for your ID:

```
function wpd_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'my_id';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'wpd_query_vars');
```

Then add an internal rule to catch incoming requests, load your database page, and set the ID query var:

```
function wpd_database_rewrites(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'database/([0-9]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*).html$',
        'index.php?pagename=database&my_id=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_database_rewrites' );
```

Then you can access the value of the ID via `get_qury_var( 'my_id' );`

Add a couple more query vars and set those via `$matches[2]` and `$matches[3]` if you also want category and title.

Comment: So close! This is exactly what I want except for one minor issue. The URL has now got a trailing forward slash. How can that be removed? `http://www.example.com/database/44/category/short-item-description.html` now becomes `http://www.example.com/database/44/category/short-item-description.html/`

Comment: A quick fix is to change the post permalink structure under Settings > Permalinks and remove the trailing slash there, which will allow no trailing slash for all permalinks. Otherwise I think you'd have to remove the canonical redirect function that WordPress uses to redirect to the version with slash, which may have other consequences.

Comment: Allelujah! Yes changing Permalinks to Custom Structure of `http://www.example.com//%postname%` has totally answered my question. You are a legend. I have been trying to get this answered for three-four days. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your converting a website to Wordpress but you want to get data from an external database?

Getting it working in the way you are describing could be quite hacky. Why not add it to the Wordpress as a custom post type. Import all the data from the old website into the new Wordpress site and then just do 301 redirects from the old urls to the new ones?

That would take care of the URL rewriting issues and you would also have the added bonus of being able to edit the content from the Wordpress admin panel if you did this too.